# Error in getResources().openRawResource when it's not used in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I need help, I don't know why I get error in line : `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource;` if it's used in non-activity class (if I declare it in `MainActivity`, it works). I need to use it in `MainActivity` line, where I pass the array list : `vardadienas= resources.readData();`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView logs;
    private List<VDienas> vardadienas = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logs);

        GetResources resources = new GetResources();

        try {
           vardadienas= resources.readData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String text = "";
        List<String> vdienas = findByDate(1,2);
        for (int a=0;a<vdienas.size();a++){
            text+= vdienas.get(a);
            text+=" ";
        }
        logs.setText(text);

    }



    private List<String> findByDate(int Menesis, int Diena){

        List<String> vardi = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<vardadienas.size();i++){
        VDienas dienas = vardadienas.get(i);
        if(Menesis == dienas.getMenesis() && Diena == dienas.getDiena()) {

            vardi=dienas.getVardi();

        }
    }
    return vardi;

    }
```

So, when I run the app, it shows me error in line:

> InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dati2);
>   error : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

```
public class GetResources extends MainActivity {

    public List<VDienas> readData() throws IOException {
        List<VDienas> vardadienas = new ArrayList<>();
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dati2);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))



        );
        String line = "";
        reader.readLine(); // skip the headers
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            // split by ';'
            String[] tokens = line.split(";");

            // read the data
            VDienas janvaris = new VDienas();
            janvaris.setMenesis(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
            janvaris.setDiena(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));


            for(int i=0; i<Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); i++ ) {
                janvaris.setVards(tokens[i+3]);

            }
            vardadienas.add(janvaris);






        }return vardadienas;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create random subclasses of `Activity`, such as your `GetResources` class.

Do not create instances of an `Activity` yourself, as you are doing with your `GetResources` class.

Either:

- Move `readData()` into `MainActivity`, or
- Have `GetResources` extend nothing, change `readData()` to `public List<VDienas> readData(Context ctxt)`, call `getResources()` on that `ctxt` parameter, and pass `this` when you create the `GetResources` instance (`new GetResources(this)`)

`getResources()` is a method on `Context`. `Activity` extends from `Context`.